# Access root document map in the $filter aggregation (MongoDb)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, filtering

I apologize for the vague question description, but I have quite a complex question regarding filtration in MongoDB aggregations. Please, see my data schema to understand the question better:

```
Company {
  _id: ObjectId
 name: string
}
```

```
License {
  _id: ObjectId
  companyId: ObjectId
  userId: ObjectId
}
```

```
User {
  _id: ObjectId
  companyId: ObjectId
  email: string
}
```

**The goal:**

I would like to query all non-licensed users. In order to do this, you would need these plain MongoDB queries:

```
const licenses = db.licenses.find({ companyId }); // Get all licenses for specific company
const userIds = licenses.toArray().map(l => l.userId); // Collect all licensed user ids

const nonLicensedUsers = db.users.find({ _id: { $nin: userIds } }); // Query all users that don't hold a license
```

**The problem:**

The code above works perfectly fine. However, in our system, companies may have hundreds of thousands of users. Therefore, the first and the last step become exceptionally expensive. I'll elaborate on this. First things first, you need to fetch a big number of documents from DB and transmit them via the network, which is fairly expensive. Then, we need to pass a huge `$nin` query to MongoDB over the network again, which doubles overhead costs.

So, I would like to perform all the mentioned operations on the MongoDB end and return a small slice of non-licensed users to avoid network transmission costs. Are there ideas on how to achieve this?

I was able to come pretty close using the following aggregation (pseudo-code):

```
db.company.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: id } }, // Step 1. Find the company entity by id
  { $lookup: {...} }, // Step 2. Joins 'users' collection by `companyId` field
  { $lookup: {...} }, // Step 3. Joins 'licenses' collection by `companyId` field
  { 
    $project: {
      licensesMap: // Step 4. Convert 'licenses' array to the map with the shape { 'user-id': true }. Could be done with $arrayToObject operator
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
       unlicensedUsers: {
             $filter: {...} // And this is the place, where I stopped
          }
     }
  }
]);
```

Let's have a closer look at the final stage of the above aggregation. I tried to utilize the [$filter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation in the following manner:

```
{
    $filter: {
     input: "$users"
     as: "user",
     cond: {
       $neq: ["$licensesMap[$$user._id]", true]
     }
  }
}
```

But, unfortunately, that didn't work. It seemed like MongoDB didn't apply interpolation and just tried to compare a raw `"$licensesMap[$$user._id]"` string with `true` boolean value.

**Note #1:**

Unfortunately, we're not in a position to change the current data schema. It would be costly for us.

**Note #2:**

I didn't include this in the aggregation example above, but I did convert Mongo object ids to strings to be able to create the `licensesMap`. And also, I stringified the ids of the `users` list to be able to access `licensesMap` properly.

**Sample data:**

**Companies collection:**

```
[
  { _id: "1", name: "Acme" }
]
```

**Licenses collection**

```
[
  { _id: "1", companyId: "1", userId: "1" },
  { _id: "2", companyId: "1", userId: "2" }
]
```

**Users collection:**

```
[
  { _id: "1", companyId: "1" },
  { _id: "2", companyId: "1" },
  { _id: "3", companyId: "1" },
  { _id: "4", companyId: "1" },
]
```

**The expected result is:**

```
[
  _id: "1", // company id
  name: "Acme",
  unlicensedUsers: [
    { _id: "3", companyId: "1" },
    { _id: "4", companyId: "1" },
  ]
]
```

Explanation: `unlicensedUsers` list contains the third and the fourth users because they don't have corresponding entries in the `licenses` collection.

Comment: "$licensesMap[$$user._id]" this is not a valid path for aggregation.Because your question is quite big, is it possible to simplify it? like focus on the stage that doesnt work(if the problem is at last project), some sample data before the problematic stage and expected output would help also

Comment: if licensesMap is an object like `{userid1 : value, userid2 : value}` and you want to get the value for `userid2` for example you can use `$getField` but only if you use string, in your case you want to use mongodb variable `$$user._id` so doesnt seems possible with like hash-map get, linear search looks like the way to get the value here, like keep the license map an array and search on it

Comment: Sure, I will provide sample data a bit later. Speaking about keeping licenses as an array. I don't think that it's a good idea as filtering in that case will produce quadratic asymptotic complexity.

Comment: yeah i know but we dont have in mongodb a function  `get("$$key")` we only have `get("key_string")` see the `$getField` operator

Comment: Hey @Takis, I updated the description and included the sample data with the desired output. Also, I tried using `$getField`, but the `$neq` operator inside `$filter` didn't recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something simple like:

```
db.usersCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "licensesCollection",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "userId",
      as: "licensedUsers"
    }
  },
  {$match: {"licensedUsers.0": {$exists: false}}},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$companyId",
      unlicensedUsers: {$push: {_id: "$_id", companyId: "$companyId"}}
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "companiesCollection",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "company"
    }
  },
  {$project: {unlicensedUsers: 1, company: {$arrayElemAt: ["$company", 0]}}},
  {$project: {unlicensedUsers: 1, name: "$company.name"}}
])
```

[playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i_e-kZqQuH0)

`users` collection and `licenses` collection, both have anything you need on the users so after the first `$lookup` that "merges" them, and a simple `$match` to keep only the unlicensed users, all that left is just formatting to the format you request.

Bonus: This solution can work with any type of id. For example [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-oN-TO_SGHW)

Comment: Yes, that would work. But unfortunately, in this case, the first `$lookup` stage will be pretty slow (somewhere `O(M*N)`), because Mongo will have to scan both `licenses` and `users` collection to perform the join operation.

I have a really big dataset and an aggregation similar to yours. And, sadly, it works fairly slow.

Comment: Actually, if you index it, it should be O(n) where n is the number of users. Should loop over the users and for each one find its license (O(1)) if hashed.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It's indexed, but there is a B-Tree index applied. I will try rebuilding the index and do some measurements

Comment: Hash indexes did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to ear it :) If it works for you please accept it, so it will be easier for others to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing a similar situation. Bear in mind that the above solution will work fast only with the `hashed` index.